# how do I fix this code

Tags: c++

I am taking an online course.

The homework question is:

> Use the rand() function to print the first 50 numbers between 1 and 100. Try to put every 5 random number in one line only. Use setw() function to align.

I currently have the following. I know that it is an infinite loop and the error I think the problem is in my `if` statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int random_number;

    srand(time(NULL));

    random_number = rand() % 100 + 1;
    cout << "50 random numbers are:" << endl;
    while (random_number < 100, rand() % 100 + 1)
    {
        cout << random_number << setw(5) << endl;
        if (random_number == 100)
            break;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: The question isn't clear to me. Are you trying to print 50 random numbers in the range `[1, 100]`? Are you okay with repetition (That is, do you want the numbers to be unique)?

Comment: The assignment is to print 50 numbers, so start with that, make a for loop that iterates 50 times printing a random number each time, then work on formatting the lines appropriately.

Comment: Also, note that: `random_number < 100, rand() % 100 + 1`. The comma operator will execute `random_number < 100`, discard it's return value, execute `rand() % 100 + 1`, and return it's return value. Which means that the expression is equivalent to `rand() % 100 + 1`.

Comment: Yes it wanted unique numbers. And @sharth, i had no idea of that thanks for the heads up!

Comment: DId any of the answers worked for you? If yes, then mark this thread as solved by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` is faulty, see previous comment. This should work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int random_number;

    srand(time(NULL));

    cout << "50 random numbers are:" << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
    {
        random_number = rand() % 100 + 1;
        cout << setw(5) << random_number << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

or, if you want to use a `while`,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int random_number;

    srand(time(NULL));

    cout << "50 random numbers are:" << endl;
    int counter=0;
    int random_number;
    while(counter<50)
    {
        counter++; 
        random_number = rand() % 100 + 1;
        cout << setw(5) << random_number << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

but just use `for` as it is more compact.

Comment: this is exactly what i needed in terms that I can comprehend at this level. Thanks!!

Comment: @nickwelsh1989 Then perhaps you should accept vsoftco's answer. That, showing appreciation in the concept of the stackexchange, encourages others to help each other.

Answer (score 1):

I understand many of above codes are good for op. For as we can see op is new to coding here is my simplified attempt.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int random_number, count=0; //Using count as a counter.
    srand(time(NULL));

    cout << "50 random numbers are:" << endl;
    //checking two conditions. count and random number generated is less than 100
    while (count <50) 
    {
        if((random_number = rand() % 100 + 1) > 100 ) continue;
        count++;
        cout<< setw(5) << random_number ;
        //Try to put every 5 random number in one line only.
        if (count %5==0) cout<<endl; 
    }

}
```

Problems with your code:

- You were generating random number only once since it was outside the
  while loop.
- No correct stopping criteria of while loop. Giving infinite loop.
- Your solution formatting wasn't as asked in the question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework, I cannot post a straight answer. However, this should count as a good demonstration of modern c++:

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0a3da1489ad5416)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator/function_input_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/random.hpp>

boost::random::variate_generator<boost::mt19937, boost::uniform_int<int> > rdngen(
        boost::mt19937(), boost::uniform_int<int>(1, 1000));

int main() {
    auto f = boost::make_function_input_iterator(rdngen, 0),
         l = boost::make_function_input_iterator(rdngen, 100);

    auto range = boost::make_iterator_range(f, l);

    using namespace boost::spirit::karma;
    std::cout << format_delimited(columns(5) [ right_align(10) [ *auto_ ] ], "\t", range) << "\n";

}
```

Comment: @OutlawLemur I don't see how that's gonna hurt him :|

Comment: It is his first week of programming. I have worked in C++ minimally for a few months, and have years of practice but this is still pretty advanced for me. It is a great answer, but not appropriate in the context

Comment: @JohanLarsson It's ok. He's got a good point. I don't really mind. I posted it as a finger-exercise for myself. It would just be shame not to post :)

Comment: +0 because while this is good code in isolation, the answer lacks explanatory exposition _and_ @Outlaw has a good point.

Comment: Although I'm sure this is 100% amazing....outlaw is right... this wizzed right over my head. haha thanks for the quick reply though glad to see how fast everyone helps!

Comment: I actually probably have upvoted this because it is brilliant... But I recently read a meta post about how you should downvote when it may be factually correct, but not appropriate. I would post the link but I cannot find it at the moment

Comment: @OutlawLemur Believe me, i've seen it. And the majority certainly didn't agree :/

Comment: @sehe I normally wouldn't... But this goes above my head even haha

Answer (score 0):

I think that for what are you posting, that you want to print 50 random numbers between 1 and 100, isn't it? If this is so, I notice the mistake is in the leave condition of the while loop. You need a variable for counting the displayed numbers and you should check if this variable has reached the 50 displayed numbers.

```
srand(time(NULL));

random_number = rand() % 100 + 1;
cout << "50 random numbers are:" << endl;
for (int i = 0;i<50;++i)
{
   random_number = rand() % 100 + 1
   cout << random_number << setw(5) << endl;
//   if (random_number == 100)
//       break;
}
system("pause");
```

In the way you have coded the leaving condition it is posible that never leaves. It is necessary that you get a 100 for exiting the loop

I hope this post was helpful for you 
Thanks regard.